# Accessing file uploads in flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads

I'm building my first flask app and am having trouble accessing my uploaded files in functions later on in my script. I'm using a variation of the basic Flask Upload script, and currently I have two forms which each take in some sort of text file. I am trying to run the input files through a function later on in my script to compare discrepancies. As it is right now I get this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename1' referenced before assignment
```

I'm trying to get my head around if this is a form issue, or a saved file issue.
Here is my upload folder:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['doc', 'docx', 'html', 'txt','rtf'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.secret_key = 'MySecretKey'

if not os.path.isdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
     os.mkdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
```

And here is one of the file uploads, the other is almost identical besides the filenames:

```
def allowed_audio_file(reference_file):
     return '.' in reference_file and \
           reference_file.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/referenceupload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_reference_file():   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
           flash('No file part')
           return redirect(request.url)
        ref_file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if ref_file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if ref_file and allowed_audio_file(ref_file.filename):
            filename1 = secure_filename(ref_file.filename)
            ref_file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename1))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_reference_file',
                                    filename1=filename1))  


    return  render_template('reference.html', filename1=filename1)


@app.route('/uploads/<filename1>')
def uploaded_reference_file(filename1):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename1)
```

Here is the full error:

```
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
  response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Jesse\eclipse-workspace\WER\src\Word_error_rate\uploads.py", line 55, in upload_reference_file
return  render_template('reference.html', filename1=filename1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename1' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `filename1` only exists if `if ref_file and allowed_audio_file(ref_file.filename):` is `True`. If it's not, and your other conditions also aren't, you will instead break out of the function with `return  render_template('reference.html', filename1=filename1)`, leading to an error.

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: Hard to say, possibly `allowed_audio_file(ref_file.filename)` is False. What do you get if you `print(ref_file.filename)`?

Comment: So if I don't include filename1=filename1 in the return I can print the filename fine, but when I include filename1=filename1 the return statement breaks before I can run the page to upload the file.

Comment: Sorry I meant - please show me what you get when you print the filename. Yes, removing `filename1` in `return  render_template('reference.html', filename1=filename1)` will remove the error, but that doesn't help you to understand why your checks fell through and you ended up returning at the bottom of the function.

Comment: I've updated the original post to display the whole error

Comment: It's always best to include the traceback in the initial question but in this case I managed to find the error without it. It's still not what I'm asking, it tells you exactly what I've already said. If you're not willing to just give the string output of `print(ref_file.filename)` then there is nothing I can suggest that might be causing the app to behave this way (OK, you know what throws the error and how to avoid the error, but presumably the code isn't following the logic you intended) <shrug>.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I can't print anything until the page is running and a file is uploaded. If I remove `filename1=filename1` in the return it prints out exactly what the filename of the upload is, otherwise the error returns if I don't remove `filename1=filename1`  .

Comment: `example.docx` is what a print looks like